# PHPUnit 10.5 bad ComparisonFailure use

Tags: phpunit

So I'm using phpunit 10.5.10 with Laravel.

The installed composer package version is 10.5.10 and my phpunit --version is 10.5.10 too, so the versions are not problem!

When I have this code:
`$response->assertJson(['error' => 'Unauthorized.']);`

And it wants to fail, I got this error:
`TypeError: PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint::fail(): Argument #3 ($comparisonFailure) must be of type ?PHPUnit\SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ComparisonFailure, SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ComparisonFailure given, called in /Users/kisssa/Desktop/adm/pkdr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/Constraints/ArraySubset.php on line 83`

The interesting part is, the fail method is in `PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint` and this class uses correctly the ComparisonFailure class. So this'd okay..

`use SebastianBergmann\Comparator\ComparisonFailure;`

I tried to delete the fail method from `PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint` but the error is still the same. But I deleted the method, so I don't know where the phpunit gets this Constraint class from. Any ideas?